# How to display an image in angular from a http call?

Tags: angular

I have an express back-end in which i have stored user avatar in mongodb. Now
i want to display it to my client side (angular 7) where there will be a div and my plan is to use `background-image:url()`. inside the url the http call will be made. here is the code:

```
   <mat-card class="container">
        <div
          [ngStyle]="{
            'background-image': 'url(' + myIdentity.avatar_url + ')'
          }"
        >
        </div>
        <mat-card-header>
          <mat-card-title>{{ myIdentity.firstName }}</mat-card-title>
          <mat-card-subtitle>({{ myIdentity.lastName }})</mat-card-subtitle>
        </mat-card-header>

        <mat-card-content>
          Joined Date:
          {{ myIdentity.createdAt | date: 'medium' }}</mat-card-content
        >
      </mat-card>
```

here is what it looks like in html. seems everything is ok.. but still cant see anything in the clint side.

```
<div _ngcontent-c12="" ng-reflect-ng-style="[object Object]" style="background-image: url(http://localhost:3000/avater/Karim)"></div>
```

Instead of `div` if I use `image tag` then its working absolute fine. But I want to use div. Please let me know how could i achieve this?

Here is how i was sending the image from the back-end:

```
app.get('/avater/:filename', (req, res) => {
      console.log(req.params.filename)
      if (req.params) {
        gfs.files.findOne({ 'filename.avaterName': req.params.filename }, (err, files) => {
          // Error checking
          if (!files || files.length === 0) {
            return res.status(404).json({
              responseCode: 1,
              responseMessage: 'error'
            });
          }

          var readstream = gfs.createReadStream({
            filename: files.filename
          });
          // set the proper content type
          res.set('Content-Type', files.contentType);
          // Return response
          return readstream.pipe(res);
        });
```

Comment: I have an idea, but I'm not sure so I'm gonna comment it instead of putting it as an answer.

First, you could try `'background-image': 'url(' + myIdentity.avatar_url | async + ')' // added async pipe` and see if it works, I have other ideas but try this one please haha see if it works (assumming the variable is an Observable, an http call, not the subscribe result, or the observer)

Comment: try giving `height` and `width` to the background and `background-size: cover;`

Comment: sorry async pipe showing error as i have already subscribed the data by http call. @FranciscoSantorelli

Comment: Not working... i have already set height and width and cover as well. nothing working. :( :( @AkhilAravind

Comment: @Kazi `" style="background-image: url(http://localhost:3000/avater/Karim)">` did you missed the file extension here

Comment: @AkhilAravind here `karim` is the param which is use to to search in the database to get the image. server response is image and with image tag its working fine. but not with the div @AkhilAravind

Comment: @Kazi bit confusing, why dont you run query for image data once you get the user data, i think there is your blocker.

Comment: i have updated my question. Can you please have a look ? I have given you the back end code and how the image was fetched.. @AkhilAravind

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194749/discussion-between-akhil-aravind-and-kazi).

Comment: I'm confused, if files is an object with property `filename`, why does it also have length? `filename: files.filename`, `files.length`. What type of object are you getting? can you put up an example from your console.log?

Comment: hi the image was saved in mongodb and it has a length property. here its look like for user karim: 
`{ _id: 5cf7bd476623751bf0536203,
  length: 5216,
  chunkSize: 261120,
  uploadDate: 2019-06-05T13:01:59.617Z,
  filename: { originalname: '72.jpg', avaterName: 'Karim' },
  md5: 'b5f8c29ed4fec75831a980bd8f898e20',
  contentType: 'image/jpeg' }
`
@FranciscoSantorelli

Comment: don't you need to add in the header 'response-type: 'image/jpeg' or something in the http call?

Comment: I have done with res.set('Content-Type', files.contentType);  @FranciscoSantorelli

Comment: and what about nesting your image in a FileReader object?